# WCF service crashed without any exceptions

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF service hosted in windows service. Unfortunately, the service has crashed and upon examining the event viewer logs, found the below error message.

**Framework Version: v4.0.30319**

> Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in
>   the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEF9A258EF (000007FEF98A0000) with exit
>   code 80131506.

We have already implemented proper exception handling and even though the service is crashing when an exception occurs. Also, we are unable to trace out what exactly is the error message from the event viewer logs.

Could you please guide me on the above error? Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Have you tried researching the error? Are you using unmanaged code wihtin the service? Does it occur on one machine or more? Have you ran a memtest on the machine?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, i have researched about the error but couldn't find any information about it. Our service connects to third party providers to fetch the data and there is high chance of interacting with unmanaged code, but we cannot change it to a managed one.

Comment: the issue is related to third party libraries being used in our service. the relevant technical team have fixed the issue and is resolved now